# How to get video height on mounting before rendering layout?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm rendering two tabs on a page. The tab content is a video player and other elements under it. The problem is that when switching tabs the layout glitches. Anyone can help me with that?

To solve this I tried with no success (on mounting height is 0):

```
  const [videoHeight, setVideoHeight] = useState<number | null>(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const { height } = videoElement.current?.getBoundingClientRect() as DOMRect;
    setVideoHeight(height);
  }, []);

      <CardMedia
        component={'video'}
        src={videourl}
        ref={videoElement}
        height={videoHeight}
        width={'100%'}
      />
```

Here's a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/video-player-mw4c98?file=/src/App.tsx

**UPD**

I tried `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect` with no success as well. I believe that is because video is not fully loaded at that moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is not with height jumping from 0 to the actual height. The height is correctly set. The thing is video elements have a default black poster that appears in a bit after you mount them on the page. I'm not sure if there is a native or better way to work around it, but it seems some people have found a solution by setting a white poster instead. If you don't want to rely on the body's background color (which is usually white), you could go with a transparent png as the poster. Here is the original question/answer I'm referring to:
[Remove black background from html5 video. Appears for a second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059315/remove-black-background-from-html5-video-appears-for-a-second)

I tested it here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/video-player-forked-5jxd7m

Comment: I tried this as well no success

Comment: What if you also initialize your state with `undefined` instead of `0`?

Comment: Just updated my answer. Please let me know if it helped.